# Are all critical points either inflection points, local minimum or local maximum?

Tags: integration, derivatives

*Question:*

- Let $f$ be a differentiable function. If the point c is a critical number, then either  it is a local maximum, or  local minimum, or an inflection point. $T/F$ ?

*My opinion:*

- If c is a critical point then f'(c)=0 or undefined. So it may local maximum and local minimum.
- If  f '(c)=∞ then c is inflection point at the same time and if f '(c)=0 it may inflection point again.
- But i can't find instance disproves this thesis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}
x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right) & x \neq 0\\
0 & x=0
\end{cases}$$

at $x=0$?

> $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$ but $0$ is not a minimum, not a maximum and not an inflexion point.

Comment: Your nick and answer very compatible. I get it thanks.

Comment: The SAME example the professor did during my  Calculus I course. 1977 AD

Comment: @Raffaele I imagine that the example is used in may Calculus courses! $f$ is an easy differentiable *locally oscillating* map!